# Keyboard Command + Delete Doesn't Move File to Trash in Finder - OSX

Tags: macos

I noticed that I can move a file in Finder to my trash can by hitting Command + the Backspace / Delete button.  If I use Command + Delete Button next to the "end" and "fn" keys, the file isn't moved.  Is there a reason I have to use the backspace / delete key and is there a way to activate the other delete key somewhere in settings?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ph3957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default, I assume you are using the USB keyboard as the WiFi / macbook keyboard dontt have it. (Which might be the reason why it is not enabled.)

The other delte key is not a delete key, it is a backspace and it actually has the backspace symbol on it. many people hate that as it confuses them,e specially if they came from a PC.

Full article:
http://lowendmac.com/mail/07/0502.html#6

"Confusing "delete" with "backspace" (because Apple has two keys named "delete" on the keyboard, one of which does forward delete and the other backward delete. Way to go, usability geniuses).

Yep, Apple has long messed up on this one. It's driven me crazy since the first Mac.

Your Logitech keyboard follows ISO/IEC 9995, the international standard for keyboard layouts. The standard appears to be up to Version 8; it's developed by ISO/IEC JTC1/SC35, which has its headquarters at AFNOR, the French national standards body. There are many national variants on the alphanumeric sections of the keyboard (e.g., for accented character sets and for local variants like the AZERTY keyboard used in France rather than the more common QWERTY), but there's uniformity that the key in the upper right corner is BACKSPACE.

Actually, there are two issues here: One is the layout of the keyboard, and the other is the bit combination produced by the keys. The BACKSPACE key is always mapped (even in Apple's mislabeled version) to the code BS (which obviously comes from BackSpace), Hex 08, and the DELETE key to the code DEL, Hex 7F. These codes go all the way back to ASCII (ANSI X3.4-1967, ISO 646-IRV-1972) and have been carried forwards in all the later coding standards (e.g., ISO 8859). The current coding standards (UNICODE or ISO/IEC 10646) address only the printing characters and leave the control sequences intact from where they were 20+ years ago. (Some of the sequences, like BEL, actually go back to Teletype usage.)"